# magento cookies not working

Tags: php, magento

I'm using

```
$id = 'WelcomeWindow';
$data = '1';
$time = time()+60*60*24*30;
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set($id, $data, $time);
```

And to get the cookie back

> $data_from_cookie =
>   Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('WelcomeWindow');

This kind of works but - when getting the cookie it doesn't show the value untill I refersh the Magento Cache within the admin area, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it, for some reason I've moved the code to be executed before anything else is delivered to the page, so I placed it at the top of head.phtml and it seems to work fine.