# How to access Cookies in Chrome after i close my Browser

Tags: php, magento, cookies

I am facing one issue when I close my chrome browser and it will not show my cookies information in where I print information using `$_COOKIE`

I set Cookies for 30 days here is the code which is used to set cookies:

```
setcookie("cookie[".$_product->getSku()."]","".$_product->getSku()."",time()+2592000,'/','new.domain.com',true);
```

my site is secure so I set `true` as last parameter

it shows correct cookies information if I am not closing my browser  but when O close my browser and come again it will not show the information which I set in cookies.

But when I show cookies information it will show me the cookies which were set earlier.

i also set setting of chrome to unchecked the option so when i close browser it will not delete my cookies too from chrome browser setting.

cookies is working correctly in FireFox eventhough if i close browser, but i can't get an idea what is the issue comes in chrome so if anybody is there which has faced this type of issue then please let me know what i can do to solve this issue

note: i also set expire time of cookies

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Probably a browser issue. Are you in private browsing mode?

Comment: yes i also set true for it too in cookies syntax

Comment: is there any option it's working perfectly in FF but not working in Chrome

Comment: Did you try to clear browser cache and cookies?

Comment: codeforest my friend actually it's work for firefox i did also refresh cached too

Answer (score 0):

Odd that it works in Firefox. I assume your Chrome installation is up to date!? Have you tried using setcookie() whist omitting the path and domain parameters to see if that alerts the behaviour in Chrome?

Comment: it's not allow to access cookies in other pages if you remove path from cookies...... i checked it

Comment: OK, are you're definitely not using Chrome in incognito mode? As cookies are always non-persistent whilst in this mode.

Comment: yes jon i am not using chrome in incognito mode! it's simple mode of chrome

Comment: Could it be the Mage core/cookie class overwriting the data? Here are some old questions relating to the core/cookie core/session models:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215807/magento-cookies-not-working
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341068/magento-frontend-session-cookie